# getOrgChart 2.0.6 compatibility with jQuery

Tags: jquery, getorgchart

I'm using getOrgChart 2.0.6, but the dependancy with jquery seems to be removed.

Now, I want to modify "clickevent" but all the example I found in the documentation area of www.getorgchart.com requires jQuery.

(ex: http://www.getorgchart.com/Documentation#clickEvent)

What is the corret syntax? Without using jQuery the event is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct syntax in version 2.0.7:

```
var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"), {
    clickNodeEvent: clickHandler,   
    dataSource: [{id: 1,parentId: null,Name: "Amber McKenzie"}, {id: 2,parentId: 1,Name: "Ava Field"}, {id: 3,parentId: 1,Name: "Evie Johnson"}]
});

function clickHandler(sender, args) {
  alert("clecked node.id " + args.node.id);
}
```

for more informmation see the documentation: http://www.getorgchart.com/Documentation#clickNodeEvent